# Refreshing static html cache on asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm busy building a website using asp.net core 2.0, and it's hosted on a Ubuntu 16.04 server with Nginx acting as a proxy. It's not a live environment but a local.

What I would like to know is, when updating static view's, eg. the about page with extra content, and upload it to the dev server, it does not update until I restart the service that the site is running under. Is there any way to get around that, so that when I upload the content, it automatically refreshes.

I've used this guide to setup Nginx and asp.net core 2.0 on the Ubuntu server :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Are you using nginx to serve the static content? If so then post your nginx config

Comment: are you talking about this ?

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

Comment: Like I said, I used the above link as a base to get the environment working

Comment: You should not be serving static files using .NET, rather server those using nginx by adding a additional route

Comment: could you give an example please, sorry I'm a noob in this.This is my first time setting up an environment like this.

Comment: Bradley did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: No i have not, still battling with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be serving static files directly from nginx instead of doing it through .NET

Assuming you have `/css`, `/js` for your assets located in your `/www/inetpub/assets` folder then you would add below to your nginx config

```
location ~* ^/(css|js)/ {
   root /www/inetpub/assets;
}
```

This will server `css` from `/www/inetpub/assets/css` folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

I will test it and get back to you. Just a question, how would i amend this to serve the rendered html as well. If i update a cshtml file and update the content